# Effect of Antenna and gain on PSD of a radio receiver

Tags: noise, antenna, radio, noise-spectral-density, power-spectral-density

I have a cheap SDR receiver and today I was trying to measure the noise in the system.
I tried to disconnect the antenna and measure the power over the frequency range of the device. I also decided to take samples varying the gain from low to high at each frequency step.

After testing different (unsuccessful) attempts of RF shielding, I thought it would be interesting to hook different antennas and see their effect.
I was quite surprised to learn that the power dropped drastically around some frequencies when I hooked an antenna for low gains, and raised a lot for high gains.

My question is what is causing the power to decrease when an antenna is plugged in?

Here are some plots of my measurements. The different curves represent different Gains. The units of the legend are  dB. All plots are at the same scale.

[image: Power distribution with no antenna]
[image: Power distribution with small monopole]
[image: Power distribution with home-made dipole]

Comment: What do the different colored lines represent?

Comment: @Bruce Abott different gains, I tried to make it more clear now. Thanks

Comment: Replace the antenna with a 50 ohm resistor to see the noise of the device itself.

Comment: Plot the two different antennas on the same axis, one gainsetting per plot. Those look relatively close, but the plots make it hard to extract the differences between the two. It's possible that your sdr is changing its input impedance as the gain changes, which would change the antenna match as the gain changes.

Comment: @user_1818839 thanks! I will try when I'm back home.

Comment: @rfdave Good comment, they do look very close indeed. I repeated the measurements with more samples per point (I was taking too few by mistake). The dips are narrower but persist and can be replicated taking several measurements. I will look at the difference when I can